# How should I replace a tub spout?

Tags: plumbing, shower

I am also having trouble with water still coming out the spout when the shower is on. When I replace the spout should I use Teflon tape (it has a set screw) and plumbers putty between the spout and shower wall?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember right, the kind with a set screw have a rubber grommet and don't need tape (if there is a threaded connection then you should use some).

Use clear silicone where it meets the wall and leave a tiny gap at the bottom for drainage.